# Background resizing not working as expected

Tags: css

I have a background image. When the window is max size, everything looks fine. But when I shrink the window, the background shrinks with it and at some point, it becomes smaller than the window and doesn't cover the entire page.

I always take all the width but not the height.

How do I solve this?

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url("background2.jpg");
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    font-family: "Courier New","Trebuchet MS", "lucida";
}
```

Comment: Can you please share demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```css
html { 
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468914627279-5d80a88fcd43?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a link where the code came from with some extra information.
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue only occurs if you don't specify a height of the html and body tags.

By adding

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

it worked fine!

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/DeathCamel57/pen/MOGjVQ)